# I want to setup Apache Metron, I have installed CentOS 7 on my Windows 7 and VMWare

Tags: apache, maven

I installed Apache Maven 3.3.9, Python 2.7, Java 1.8, Ansible 2.0.0.2, Vagrant 1.9.6 and VirtualBox 5.1 on CentOS 7

When I run 'vagrant up', there is an error of Maven dependencies and also Ansible failed to setup successfully and this also happens when I do 'vagrant provision'.

Where do I need to run the command `mvn clean install packages`?

Answer (score 0):

try running the command within the metron folder.

1. Open Terminal, run:

   ```
   cd metron    
   mvn clean install
   ```